# Find $i$ by formula ${F \over A}={{(1+i)^n-1}\over{i}}$

Tags: power-series

(Uniform Series
Compound Amount - Annuity
Converts a uniform amount (annuity) - to a future value)

> Find $i$ by formula ${F \over A}={{(1+i)^n-1}\over{i}}$

where

$F$ = future value

$A$ = uniform amount per period

$i$ = interest rate

$n$ = numbers of periods

My attempt:

${F \over A}={{(1+i)^n-1}\over{i}}$

${F \over A}={{[1+ni+{{n(n-1)i^2}\over{2!}}+ {{n(n-1)(n-2)i^3}\over{3!}}+...]-1}\over{i}}$

${F \over A}={{ni+{{n(n-1)i^2}\over{2!}} +{{n(n-1)(n-2)i^3}\over{3!}}+...}\over{i}}$

${F \over A}={{i[n+{{n(n-1)i}\over{2!}} +{{n(n-1)(n-2)i^2}\over{3!}}+...]}\over{i}}$

${F\over A}= n+{{n(n-1)i}\over{2!}}+ {{n(n-1)(n-2)i^2}\over{3!}}+...$

What can I do now?

Comment: You won't be able to find an "exact" solution in general. This is a polynomial equation of degree $n$ which cannot always be solved for $n \ge 5$. However, you can turn yourself to numerical solutions. Mr. EXCEL can do the job for you, i.e NPER function.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Although you are most probably right, "in general" does not imply "in this particular case". Maybe this can be solved via some clever algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get an explicit solution for $i$ and you need some numerical method (such as Newton) to solve of the equation
$$a={{(1+i)^n-1}\over{i}}$$ You can consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=(1+i)^n-a\,i-1$$ $$f'(i)=n(1+i)^{n-1}-a$$ and Newton iterates would given by
$$i_{k+1}=i_k-\frac{f(i_k)}{f(i_k)}$$ This should converge quite fast starting from a "reasonable" estimate $i_0$.

As you did, if you want an approximation, since $i$ is small, use the Taylor expansion built at $i=0$ (you wrote it) to get
$$a=n+\frac{n(n-1) }{2}  \,i+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} i^2 +\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24} i^3 +O\left(i^4\right)$$ and use [series reversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) to get
$$i=\frac{2 (a-n)}{(n-1) n}+\frac{4 (2-n) (a-n)^2}{3 (n-1)^2 n^2}+\frac{2 \left(5
   n^2-17 n+14\right) (a-n)^3}{9 (n-1)^3 n^3}+O\left((a-n)^4\right)$$ To make it looking nicer, define $x=\frac{2(a-n)}{n(n-1)}$ and get, *as an approximation*,
$$i=x+\frac{2-n}{3} x^2+\frac{5 n^2-17 n+14}{36} 
   x^3+O\left(x^4\right)\tag 1$$

For illustration, let us try with $a=30$, $n=20$ and $i_0=x=\frac 1 {19}$; the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & i_n \\
 0 & 0.052631579 \\
 1 & 0.043476963 \\
 2 & 0.040921127 \\
 3 & 0.040716395 \\
 4 & 0.040715105
\end{array}
\right)$$ 
Uisng $(1)$, we should get $i \approx \frac{587}{13718}\approx 0.0428$ which could be a better starting point for Newton method. But, since we need to iterate, the simplest is just to start using $i_0=x=\frac{2(a-n)}{n(n-1)}$.

However, we can improve quite much the *estimate* pushing the Taylor series to high order and to transform the resulting series to an $[n+1,n]$ Padé approximant. This would write
$$i_{(n)}=x \frac{c_0+\sum_{k=1}^n c_k x^k } {c_0+\sum_{k=1}^n d_k x^k  }$$ where the coefficients $c_k$ and $d_k$ are polynomials in $n$. For example,
$$i_{(0)}=x$$
$$i_{(1)}=x \frac{12+(n+1) x } {12+(5 n-7) x }$$
$$i_{(2)}=x \frac{(1980 n-2340)+\left(720 n^2-1080 n+360\right) x+\left(16 n^3-12 n+4\right)
   x^2 } {(1980 n-2340)+\left(1380 n^2-3180 n+1920\right) x+\left(201 n^3-720 n^2+873
   n-366\right) x^2 }$$ and so on.

Applied to the above example, this would give
$$i_{(0)}=\frac 1 {19}\approx 0.0526316\qquad i_{(1)}=\frac{83}{2033}\approx 0.0408264\qquad i_{(2)}=\frac{345316}{8481049}\approx 0.0407162$$ to be compared to the exact solution $0.0407151$.

Comment: Continuing with $i_{(3)}$ leads to an absolute error of $8.4 \times 10^{-9}$ for the worked example.